# What do +(4,3) and -(4,3) mean? A plus or minus sign in front of a parenthesized pair of numbers

Tags: javascript, operators

I am trying to understand this logic in javascript

```js
console.log(+(4,3)); //3
    
console.log(+(3,4)); //4
    
console.log(-(4,3));//-3
```

I know it's stupid question, but I am just trying to understand the logic under the hood

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for editing title.